# Excel formula for finding average value in a discountinue serie of dates

Tags: excel

I am extracting data from an account statement which you can see simplified in the image in the columns A:B in red:

[image]

On A the date (in order ascending but not necessarily incremental by one) and often duplicated due to multiple account entries) and on B the fund value. 
If there are days missing, the fund value is the one of the last displayed day

=> I need to for each row on C, the average of fund since the first entry of the series (January 1st).

I can do it easily if I bring to a sequential order the fund values as I did in columns G:H but I would like to avoid this method and find a formula that placed in columnC gives me the average value. Possibly no VBA

Thanks

----ADDED---

the result I would like to see and the file example
http://www.filedropper.com/example_29

Comment: Using the sort option for the subsequent order, use the remove duplicate option in to remove duplicates, then use formula `=Sum($B$2:B2)/Day(A2)` to get the average.

Comment: Thanks Pete but removing duplicates is not an option as every row contains valuable information I cannot drop. (in the image I simplified the real file)

Comment: How about an extra column that adds the frequency and then you can use a `sumif function` to add it regardless of duplicates?

Comment: Pete, not sure I understand what you mean
My biggest issue is to calculate the average considering also that funds are present also in days which are not diplayed (for istance 12,13,14,15 jan has 12,000 that must go into the average)

Not sure if this helps but I have attached a links to download the file with the results I would like to see

Please note I cannot delete rows but no problem to work in columns to the right

Comment: Hope my answer below works for you.

Comment: Actually your solution does work until jan 11th, but after that is not ok as values for jan16th and jan20th differs from the correct value. Reason are the values for 12,13,14,15 jan (12,000), and 17,18,19 (9,000) which are not considered. You see what I mean?

Comment: Oh now I see what you are saying, but I cannot think of a way on how to solve it without vba.

Comment: yep me neither. i found some solution multiply values for missing dates (i.e. 12,000 x 4 to cover 12,13,14,15 jan ) and then summing them but it uses 3 or 4 column to the right and is not really elegant

Comment: Why do you want to avoid VBA?

Comment: no special reason actually. It is a control file and that would be the only script in it, just that. I am working today and developing your idea of frequency, if I come up with something I will post it. thanks for the support

Comment: I still cannot think of an elegant solution, but my answer below should get the right result.

Comment: wow! well if yours is not elegant, not sure what you would say about mine which spans across 3 columns.... Amazing work Pete, quite creative! thanks a lot

Comment: No worries Marco, glad to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following formula:

> =(IF(DAY(A3)-DAY(A2)>=1,(C2*DAY(A2)+B3+((DAY(A3)-DAY(A2)-1)*B2))/DAY(A3),C2))

[image]

Note that the dates need to be in subsequent order and field C2 needs to be hard-coded for my solution to work.